# Open photo in Dialog using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following HTML code that shows a simple photo album in a part of the window of my Angular project. Since the photos are shown small, i wanted to put a click event that when you click on the image, the image is shown on a window. But the problem is that the it always opens in a new window. I want the image to be opened in a dialog. Is there any option the show this image in a big dialog when clicked?

```html
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photo">
  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="photo" (error)="errorHandler($event)" onclick="myDialog(this.src)" alt="Kampus Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">

   </ng-template>
   </ngb-carousel>
```

```js
myDialog(imgSrc): void {
      let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(imgSrc, {
        height: '400px',
        width: '600px',
      });

    }
```

Comment: Since you are using window.open, it will open image in new tab/new window. If you want to show image in dialog, then use dialog box and pass the src value of the image there.

Comment: Updated the code but still i get no photo.

Comment: Change onclick="myDialog(this.src)" to (click)="myDialog(photo)". This is because we are using angular method, we have to invoke using angular way of handling events.